# Macports の database 再構築

Tags: macos

Macports で新しくパッケージをインストール中に kernel panic を引き起こし, 再起動したところ, registry.db が壊れていたため, registry.db を消した上で macports を再インストールした.

その結果として, /opt/local/ 以下には, 「以前の macports でインストールしたパッケージ」が含まれているにもかかわらず, /opt/local/var/macports/registry/registry.db には「何をインストールしたか」のデータが一切書き込まれていない状態が生じている.

そこで, インストールしたパッケージの情報から, 「registry.db」を構築する方法は無いでしょうか.
それとも, やはり /opt/local/ 以下を全部削除した上で, 再度 macports からインストールし直すほういいでしょうか.

Comment: すべて再構築することで解決しました.

Comment: 自己解決した場合、できれば回答として手順を投稿し、ベストアンサーにお選び頂けますか